# StepVerifier expectNoEvent for 0ms does not work (want to check for no delay for special cases)

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have to create a per-customer backpressure, and implemented this with returning a `Mono.justOrEmpty(authentication).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(calculatedDelay));`

This seems to be working fine in my unit-tests, BUT if I have a calculatedDelay of 0, I can't test this.  This snippet returns a `java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected end during a no-event expectation`:

```
@Test
public void testSomeDelay_8CPUs_Load7() throws IOException {
  when(cut.getLoad()).thenReturn("7");
  when(cut.getCpuCount()).thenReturn(8L);
  when(authentication.getName()).thenReturn("delayeduser");

  Duration duration = StepVerifier
  .withVirtualTime(() -> cut.get(Optional.of(authentication))) 
  .expectSubscription()  // swallow subscribe event
  .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofMillis(0)) // here is the culprit
  .expectNextCount(1) 
  .verifyComplete(); 
}
```

I don't know how to check for the cases, where I'm expected no delay at all.  This is BTW the same, when I return a Mono.justOrEmpty(authentication) (without any delayed subscription).  I can't seem to check, that I have created the correct non-delayed flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this is a corner case that is hard to cover. Especially when you know that `foo.delayElement(0)` is actually simply returning `foo` unmodified.

What you could do is test the delay differently, by appending an `elapsed()` operator:

```
Duration duration = StepVerifier
  .withVirtualTime(() -> cut.get(Optional.of(authentication))
     .elapsed() //this will get correct timing of 0 with virtual time
     .map(Tuple2::getT1) //we only care about the timing, T2 being the value
  ) 
  .expectNext(calculateDelay)
  .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: Excellent idea, thanks!
Before the .expectNext... part I put a .thenAwait(Duration.ofDays(1)), so if my unit-test ever has a wrong calculation, it won't just hang, but fail.